# Joda Time gives wrong time zone

Tags: java, jodatime

I'm using the [Joda time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) (1.6) libraries and it keeps returning DateTime objects with the wrong time zone, British Summer Time instead of GMT.

My Windows workstation (running JDK 1.6.0_16) thinks it's in GMT and if I get the default time zone from the JDK date/time classes it is correct (GMT). I get the same behaviour on our Linux servers as well. I thought it could be an error in the time zone database files in Joda so I rebuilt the jar with the latest database but with no change.

```
import java.util.TimeZone;
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.DateTimeZone;
import org.joda.time.LocalTime;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import org.joda.time.format.ISODateTimeFormat;

public class TimeZoneTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {                
        DateTimeFormatter timeParser = ISODateTimeFormat.timeParser();
        TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getDefault();
        System.out.println(timeZone.getID()); // "Europe/London"
        System.out.println(timeZone.getDisplayName()); // "Greenwich Mean Time"

        DateTimeZone defaultTimeZone = DateTimeZone.getDefault();
        System.out.println(defaultTimeZone.getID()); //"Europe/London"
        System.out.println(defaultTimeZone.getName(0L)); //"British Summer Time"

        DateTime currentTime = new DateTime();
        DateTimeZone currentZone = currentTime.getZone();
        System.out.println(currentZone.getID()); //"Europe/London"
        System.out.println(currentZone.getName(0L)); //"British Summer Time"            
    }
}
```

Debugging through the static initialiser in `org.joda.time.DateTimeZone` I see that the `System.getProperty("user.timezone")` call gives `"Europe/London"` as expected.

Comment: expanded answer to provide explanation of real problem

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Ok, to get to the root of this you have to familiarize with what British Summer Time actually means and when it was in place. To make it short you pass `0L` to `getName()` which is `1970-01-01T00:00:00Z` so `DefaultTimeZone` looks up the name of the timezone at that moment. Which was British Summer Time.

> From: http://www.nmm.ac.uk/explore/astronomy-and-time/time-facts/british-summer-time
>
> In 1968 clocks were advanced one hour
>   ahead of GMT on 18 February and
>   remained so until British Standard
>   Time, during which clocks were kept in
>   advance of GMT all year, came into
>   force between 27 October 1968 and 31
>   October 1971.

If you instead would pass in the right amount of milliseconds since `1970-01-01T00:00:00Z`. e.g. by doing

```
defaultTimeZone.getName(new GregorianCalendar().getTimeInMillis())
```

You would get the correct string too. Basically you just fed the `getName()` method the wrong parameter thus ended up with an unexpected result.

If you want to check in detail check the files in `org/joda/time/tz/src` of joda source to see how joda determines time zones.

---

Instead of

```
defaultTimeZone.getName(0L)
```

you could use

```
defaultTimeZone.toTimeZone().getDisplayName()
```

which does it for me.

Comment: Awesome. Who'd have thought. I'd literally said "There's no way that 1st Jan 1970 was in British Summer Time". More fool me.

This also explains the underlying problem that lead to the question which was parsing "10:00:00.0000000+00:00" with  ISODateTimeFormat.timeParser() resulted in a DateTime in GMT+1. This is because Joda has no independent notion of Time and Date so parses this time to relative to 1st Jan 1970 which, as you pointed out was GMT+1! Crazy. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It may interest you to see the static initialiser for the DateTimeZone class in 1.6:

```
static {
    setProvider0(null);
    setNameProvider0(null);

    try {
        try {
            cDefault = forID(System.getProperty("user.timezone"));
        } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
            // ignored
        }
        if (cDefault == null) {
            cDefault = forTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
        }
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
        // ignored
    }

    if (cDefault == null) {
        cDefault = UTC;
    }
}
```

My guess is that you have a `user.timezone` property defined (and set to BST).  Otherwise, it looks like Joda should create its own timezone instance based on the JDK time zone; and I'd expect any bugs in this area, especially converting a GMT zone, would have been picked up by now.

Comment: user.timezone gives "Europe/London" (I've added this to the question).